# Implementing captue logic method into update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working on a chess app and I am trying to figure out how to implement the move_to! method, which performs the capture logic, to happen in the update action on the controller. The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to even call the method. Would I need to rewrite the whole update action in the controller or..?

Here is the update action:

```
def update 
  @highlighted_piece = Piece.find(params[:id])
  @game = @highlighted_piece.game
  @x_pos = params[:piece][:x_position]
  @y_pos = params[:piece][:y_position]
  @highlighted_piece.update_attributes({ x_position: @x_pos, y_position: @y_pos})
  redirect_to @game
end
```

here is the capture logic:

## Capture logic

```
def move_to!(new_x, new_y)
    if Piece.where(x_position: new_x, y_position: new_y).exists?
        newpiece = Piece.find_by(x_position: new_x, y_position: new_y)
        if self.color != newpiece.color
            #perform capture
            newpiece.update_attributes(:x_position => nil, :y_position => nil)
        else
            return false
        end
    else
        return false
    end
    if self.update_attributes(:x_position => new_x, :y_position => new_y)
        @has_moved = true
    end
end
```

I was thinking I could just call move_to! on my @highlighted_piece, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: That was is it.. I can't belive I didn't notice that. It works when I actually capture a piece, but not when I move to an empty square like you said.

Thank you.

Comment: Alright, moved to answer. Actually I typed in the answer first. But I just wanted to confirm it through comments, because I thought maybe you really have planned to make it move like that (capture logic hehe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_to!` should work if you place it as an instance method for the `Piece` class.

But what I found wrong is that the `else` part to `if Piece.where(x_ ...` makes it ignore movements to empty slots. I mean say that there is no piece placed at new_x and new_y, then you should be able to move the piece to the empty location right ? But that `else` parts just makes it look like nothing has happened. That should be the cause.